# Google static map issue (not displaying)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have very strange issue with static google maps on my android device.

I have [static image map](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=11&markers=color:orange%7C45.7583,6.53815&size=500x300&sensor=false&visual_refresh=true).

When I connect to the Internet with Wi-Fi - this map looks well in browser, but when I connect 3G - I see this:

[image]

Why I can't see map with 3G?

Comment: Static maps has a daily view usage limit of 25,000 map views. The image you are seeing is what is displayed when you have used up the daily view count. I'm not sure how they track static map views, if it's mac address or external ip address, but it seems like it must be over a certain connection type. try again tomorrow;

Comment: @domji84 I have seen this image yesterday and few days ago too. And have no problem with Wi-Fi. I don't think that problem in limit usage.

Comment: really strange. i definitely remember seeing that image when usage limit was reached. thats what the icon is. no idea why this would work on wifi and not 3g...

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same problem, and the problem lies with your telecom provider. Google blocks them I think (or the ip address that you get from the telecom provider is always over the limit).
Use a proxy script on your server and direct the call there. Make sure though you check the limit on nr of queries!